# 10 million row table MySQL/ myisam 18 seconds to process?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, myisam

This query:

```
 SELECT picturesaddress.id
   FROM picturesaddress
  WHERE picturesaddress.id NOT
  IN (

  SELECT userdata.id
    FROM userdata
   )
```

10 million rows in each table, tale 18 seconds.

-Myisam
-id is primary key in both

[image: Explain]

As far as I remember they are in partition mode both tables.

Is that time correct?
Can be optimized?

Running in shared hosted server.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You could use something other than NOT IN

Comment: Given 10 million records and the use of the **IN** clause, I think it's normal. But to increase performance, I juergen's solution of using a left join should do the job.

Comment: If both tables have 10 million rows and the explain says that it is using indexes, then the performance will be hard to improve without getting better hardware.

Comment: Yes, in fact you are right, i have tested again:

NOT IN = 25 seconds
LEFT join= 21 seconds.

Seems that there is no so much difference

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `left join`

```
SELECT picturesaddress.id
FROM picturesaddress
LEFT JOIN userdata on userdata.id = picturesaddress.id
WHERE userdata.id IS NULL
```

The `IN` clause could get slow with many records in the list.

Comment: NOT IN 0 25 seconds
LEFT join 21 seconds.

No much difference it seems.

Comment: On what columns do you have keys on those 2 tables?